# Add A TextBox To A WPF-Canvas Programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add a TextBox to a WPF-Canvas. But if I execute the Program, nothing happens. Some ideas, clues, etc?

Here my **Code-behind:**

```
private void Main_Canvas_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
   {
       TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
       textBox.Width = 250;
       Canvas.SetLeft(textBox, Main_Canvas.Width / 2);
       Canvas.SetTop(textBox, Main_Canvas.Height / 2);
       Main_Canvas.Children.Add(textBox);
    }
}
```

Here my **XAML**:

```
<Canvas x:Name="Main_Canvas" KeyUp="Main_Canvas_KeyUp" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your canvas doesn't have the focus. Set it's `Focusable` to `true` and make sure that has focus with calling `Focus()` in windows `Loaded` event.

Xaml:

```
<Canvas x:Name="Main_Canvas" KeyUp="Main_Canvas_KeyUp" Focusable="True" />
```

Window `Loaded` event handler:

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
        Main_Canvas.Focus();
 }
```

Comment: @TimoMüller Thats another question. If you want to bring it to center, use `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` instead of `Width` and `Height`. Second thing is that you should consider the width and height of `Textbox` to bring it to exact center.